# What’s this raspberry fungus?

Tags: fungus, raspberries

I have a white powder/fungus showing up on my raspberries and actually my blackberries too. [image][image]
**Does anyone know what this is and how to treat it if necessary?** My 18 month old eats off of this so non toxic needed please. 
Zone 5 SW of Chicago IL USA